# WTForms SelectField not properly coercing for booleans

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Here is my code:

```
class ChangeOfficialForm(Form):
    is_official = SelectField(
        'Officially Approved',
        choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')],
        validators=[DataRequired()],
        coerce=bool
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Update status')
```

For some reason, `is_official.data` is always `True`. I suspect that I am misunderstanding how coercing works.

Answer (score 12):

While you've passed bools to the choices, only strings are used in HTML values.  So you'll have the choice values `'True'` and `'False'`.  Both of these are non-empty strings, so when the value is coerced with `bool`, they both evaluate to `True`.  You'll need to use a different callable that does the right thing for the `'False'` string.

You also need to use the `InputRequired` validator instead of `DataRequired`.  Checking the data fails if the data is False-like, while checking the input will validate as long as the input is not empty.

```
SelectField(
    choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')],
    validators=[InputRequired()],
    coerce=lambda x: x == 'True'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a quite old question but never the less:

```py
def coerce_bool(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x == "True" if x != "None" else None
    else:
        return bool(x) if x is not None else None

wtf.SelectField(
    choices=[(None, ""),(True, "Yes"), (False, "No")],
    coerce=coerce_bool
)
```

SelectField calls `coerce` in both directions:

- when processing python data applied to field, and
- when processing data over the wire from the form

that is the reason for checking is the value str or not and making an explicit comparison of values.